# Autofac lazy TypedParameter

Tags: autofac

In `Autofac` is it possible to make `TypedParameter` lazy? Even more, I need access to container when injecting parameter. Code could look like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<RootService>()
    .WithParameter(TypedParameter.From(c => c.Resolve<IChildService>(key)));
```

#### Update

Based on Nick's answer I've created the following helper method:

```
public static class TypedResolvedParameter 
{
    public static ResolvedParameter From<T>(Func<IComponentContext, T> factory)
    {
        return new ResolvedParameter(
            (pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(T),
            (pi, c) => factory(c));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for `ResolvedParameter`, also available as an overload to `WithParameter()`:

```
builder.RegisterType<RootService>()
  .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IChildService),
                 (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IChildService>(key));
```